one question about coordinate(linear-algebra)
Problem 1. For the following given basis $S = \{\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2\}$, find the coordinate vector for $\vec{w}$ that is relative to the basis $S$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$:
(a) $S = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ and $\vec{w} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ −7 \end{pmatrix}$
(b) $S = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ and $\vec{w} =\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$

What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

What is your question?

For (a) The coordinate vector would be $$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
And for (b) The coordinate vector would be $$\begin{pmatrix}a \\\ \frac{b-a}{2} \end{pmatrix}$$

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
